# Windows 10 spinning dots on black screen

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, boot, grub

So, I was using Windows 10 latest beta release. I wanted to delete old files(Windows.old) so I used CC Cleaner. I cleaned everything even registry but now my PC doesn't start. I have done this several times but this is the first time I faced this boot issue.

After Windows 10 logo screen the screen turns black and there are circular dots that keeps on spinning for long time.

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/48zrkb/windows_10_stuck_at_spinning_circle_login_screen/) post from Reddit says unplug everything out from USB slots. I did that but still no luck. Same issue can't pass the black screen with circular load/spin

Please help me fix this. I can't loose any data from my hard disk including the C drive that has all the data.

Also I have dual boot of Windows 10 with Ubuntu. GRUB bootloader.

I can't seem to enter safe mode. Don't know how. Lastly I don't have bootable pendrive for Windows 10(latest version beta). I downloaded free windows 10 pro. So, I have old iso file for Windows pro but not the latest version

Comment: How long is "a long time?"

Comment: @DrZoo 20-30 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Windows Pro ISO will still work to fix any startup problem.

Boot from the Windows CD or USB, and click on the "Repair" link.  From here you can click on "Troubleshoot", "Advanced Options", and "Startup Repair".

This will try to repair the system to allow it to boot.

If that doesn't work, boot again, and go to "Troubleshoot" and "Reset this PC".  This will basically put Windows 10 back to stock, but it will not delete any of your files/documents/photos.

Be aware that after doing this, you may need to boot from an Ubuntu disk/usb and reinstall GRUB afterwards.

For future reference, do not use CC Cleaner to remove your old files.  Windows 10 has it built-in.  Right-click your hard drive in "My Computer" and to go properties.  From there, click on the "Disk Cleanup" button.  On the Disk Cleanup window, click on "Clean up System Files".  Here you will have a list where you can put a checkmark next to "Previous Windows Installations".  This will properly remove them.

Comment: But it's dual boot how to boot via pendrive? Will grub bootloader not mess up?

Comment: If you boot from a pen drive, it will completely bypass GRUB.  As I noted in my answer, you will likely have to reinstall GRUB after Windows 10 is fixed.