# How to Reset Windows 10 to a clean state from Troubleshooting Mode

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, windows.old

I have made a stupid thing deleting the windows.old folder with CCleaner. I have read already the question [Windows 10 spinning dots on black screen](https://superuser.com/questions/1129255/windows-10-spinning-dots-on-black-screen) , which describes my problem but the answer doesn't solve my problem.

I have downloaded the windows 10 installation to an USB memory, but is not possible to use the Repair functionality when I boot from the memory, so my last option was to reset the system to a clean state, this option is not available when you boot directly from the usb/dvd, says that I need to log on and execute the installation program. Since I'm just able to log on using Troubleshooting Mode and from the Troubleshooting Mode is not possible to run the installation program what can I do then?

I can not format hdd and reinstall because my laptop came with Win 7 and I have upgraded to Win 10 for free and this is not available anymore.

Comment: *I can not format hdd and reinstall because my laptop came with Win 7 and I have upgraded to Win 10 for free and this is not available anymore.* - Since your system already has Windows 10 installed, you can simply install Windows 10, and it will automatically activate.  A typical installation of Windows 10 would allow you to access the Advanced Startup recovery environment.  Within this environment, the ability to Reset your installation, should be available.  Of course I personally have never been sucessful in performing a Reset when my installation was already broken.

Comment: @Ramhound, yes, I have access to the Advanced Startup Recovery environment but all the options that I've already tried fails. The only one that seems to be possible is to format the disk and reinstall the system. and I can't keep the current OS due this: **Windows can not be installed on the disk. The selected volume is the GTP partition style.**

Comment: *Windows can not be installed on the disk. The selected volume is the GTP partition style.* - This means you need to boot your installation media in UEFI only mode instead of enabling Legacy Mode/CSM

Comment: @Ramhound do I need to format the usb memory I'm using different to accomplish that?

Comment: I know nothing about your installation media and how it was created.  If your installation media has the required EFI drivers then you don't have to  create a new installation media.